# use an array which is defined in another file using react?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-router

I have a react component that I use it in some routes.
the component needs some data witch is different in routes. The component is like below:

```
import React from "react";

class ChangeView extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <button type="button" className="btn open-modal" title="change view">
                    <i className="fas fa-eye"></i>
                </button>
                <div id="ms">
                    <ul>{data}</ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default ChangeView;
```

and a sample route:

```
import React , {Component} from 'react';
import ChangeView from 'ChangeView';
class Firewall extends Component {
  render() {
    const data = [
       {name:"smith",age:20},
       {name:"nik",age:10},
       {name:"mosh",age:45}
    ];
    return(
      <ChangeView />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: what do you want? to pass data from the parent or you want to fetch inside the child?

Comment: @Udit I think I want the second one.

Comment: check the answer, if it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the component try to pass data like this :

```
import React , {Component} from 'react';
import ChangeView from 'ChangeView';
class Firewall extends Component {
  render() {
    const data = [
       {name:"smith",age:20},
       {name:"nik",age:10},
       {name:"mosh",age:45}
    ];
    return(
      <ChangeView data={data} />
    )
  }
}
```

and in the child ChangeView component access it using

```
props.data //functional components
```

or

```
 this.props.data //class components
```

Comment: No problem Mate :)

Answer (score 0):

this is totally okay if we are sending data from parent to child but if I want the reverse process then how to implement means passing data from child to parent

Comment: you can do that as well. by calling functions from the child, in fact, you can pass the function as a prop and call it from child to trigger value change.